# Where to put DOM interaction on scalable javascript architecture

Tags: javascript, architecture

I'm a bit confused at the moment regarding how to have a more maintainable javascript architecture. I might be out of the track, but I would say that almost 50% of my code involves the DOM hence use my base library (jQuery).

I've checked [1] Nicholas Zakas' scalable application architecture design: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/theater/video.php?v=zakas-architecture and [2]  Addy Osmani Patterns For Large-Scale JavaScript Application Architecture http://addyosmani.com/largescalejavascript/ .

I have a one page application style, with lots of content being fetched via ajax and DOM elements being added dynamically. My main question is: How can I separate the code into small re-usable blocks if I'm using jQuery (or any other base library) to manipulate the DOM.

Let's just pick a task list module for example. I understand that the module could look like this:

```
var TaskList = function() {
  addTask = function() {
    ...
  };

  removeTask = function() {
    ...
  };

  return {
    addTask: addTask,
    removeTask: removeTask
  }
}();
```

Where should the DOM elements events registration be written, the ajax call to save, load, or delete a task, appending a new task to a DOM element, etc.

I have no problem committing to having jQuery on the module as a dependency, but if there is a better way I think I missed it from the two resources above and I would love to know it.

I just want to have a more elegant way of maintaining the growing javascript because I'm tired of spaghetti ;)

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are going to develop a single page application you are going to have many visual modules that will be displayed at a current step and then they will be replaced by others.

You can follow the MVC pattern (Model-Controller-View), with each visual element being a separate entity with its own code for DOM manipulation and the business logic stored in separate classes.

One way would be:

```
<html>
  <head>
   ....
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content"> 
    <!--The main container view that can handle the replacement of smaller views -->
      <div id="toolbar"_container">
        <!-- container for menu bar or tool bar that can also has its contained 
             sub-views replaced -->
      </div>
      <div id="main_content_container">
        ....
      </div>
      <div id="properties_panel">
       .....
      </div>
    </div>      
  </body>
</html>
```

The main container can hold all the smaller container, with everyone accommodating a different view controller that has it's own DOM manipulation code, (which also has the benefit of being able to be loaded dynamically on demand and so reduce your initialize load time).

Every view can have a couple module that will perform the 'actions' and which will communicate with a third module (optional) that will take care of the I/O with databases, sockets, files, etc.

Hope it helped!

Comment: Adopting a library such as knockoutjs which enabled MVVM could also help organise your code in a way where it is clearer on ui interaction.

Comment: That's pretty much how I'm set up already in terms of HTML structure. The app is already in production. I'm more interested in javascript atm, from what you've said you're suggesting I create two "javascript class" if we can say one controller and one view and have the DOM code on the view is that it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) or you can explore [CQRS](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cqrs/info) (and related patterns) for more custom, complex and decoupled solution. It all depends on complexity of your app (and potential future growth).

You can also check out [some of this posts](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/author/derickbailey/). There are couple of good ones that targets your question in a concrete examples ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Keep Business Logic and Display Logic Separate**

This applies to more than the DOM though. Many APIs, both in the browser and in Node, are designed around firing and listening to events or waiting for other types of asynchronous work to complete. A rule of thumb is that if you are writing a lot of anonymous callback functions, your code may not be easy to test.

```
// hard to test
$('button').on('click', () => {
    $.getJSON('/path/to/data')
        .then(data => {
            $('#my-list').html('results: ' + data.join(', '));
        });
});

// testable; we can directly run fetchThings to see if it
// makes an AJAX request without having to trigger DOM
// events, and we can run showThings directly to see that it
// displays data in the DOM without doing an AJAX request
$('button').on('click', () => fetchThings(showThings));

function fetchThings(callback) {
    $.getJSON('/path/to/data').then(callback);
}

function showThings(data) {
    $('#my-list').html('results: ' + data.join(', '));
}
```

**Use Callbacks or Promises with Asynchronous Code**

The most common way to solve this problem is to pass a callback function as a parameter to the function that runs asynchronously. In your unit tests you can run your assertions in the callback you pass.

```
// hard to test; we don't know how long the AJAX request will run
function fetchData() {
    $.ajax({ url: '/path/to/data' });
}

// testable; we can pass a callback and run assertions inside it
function fetchDataWithCallback(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/path/to/data',
        success: callback,
    });
}

// also testable; we can run assertions when the returned Promise resolves
function fetchDataWithPromise() {
    return $.ajax({ url: '/path/to/data' });
}
```

[Here is the details](https://www.toptal.com/javascript/writing-testable-code-in-javascript)